# Replace the carousel dots with values in jQuery unslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unslider

I am trying to use the unslider jQuery plugin to browse through a timeline-esque list of events. Instead of the dots that are typically used i want them to be replaced by actualy year values so you can see what year you are on and browse through.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.timelineSlider').unslider();
    });
```

The function is being called on a list of elements with each element having a 'year' attribute which is the value i would want to replace the dots with but how can one edit the existing plugin to include this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find how to do that from the unislider options but the dots are actually

elements with some CSS (for instance text-indent: -999em;). 
So if you do want to replace them with values, you just have to adjust that CSS.